# SSH Mysql query result

Tags: mysql, string, shell, ssh

I'm trying to pass a query result to an SSH command.

```
command $queryresult
```

The query result can be one or more then one row and in case of more than one row, I need to concatenate them.

If I run mysql command with **-N** and **-e** parameters,

> ```
> mysql -u $MUSER -p$MPASS -D $DBS -N -e "$QUERY6"
> ```

I obtain one result per row

```
result1 
result2
```

Is there a way to separate them by a space?

```
result1 result2
```

Query is

```
SELECT view_id 
FROM mview_state 
WHERE STATUS != 'idle' AND (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() + 60000 - updated) > 1800
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GROUP_COCAT

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(mview_state.view_id SEPARATOR ' ') view_id 
FROM mview_state 
WHERE `STATUS` != 'idle' AND (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() + 60000 - mview_state.updated) > 1800 
GROUP BY view_id
```

> Sidenote:
>
> `STATUS` is a MySQL Keyword and should ideally not be used as a column name. Column names in MySQL should be universally lower case.

Comment: `STATUS` is a MySQL Keyword and for the sake of clarity of this answer should be clearly defined as a column name (and not be capitalised as currently it looks like a MySQL Command (STATUS not idle) rather than a query criteria. Thanks